# How to enable the "middle" button of Apple's new Magic Mouse?

Tags: mouse, magic-mouse

The [Magic Mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Mouse) seems to be a vast improvement over the old [Mighty Mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Mighty_Mouse) after using it for a few hours. However, I just discovered that there seems to be no way to execute a "middle" click.

I use middle-click all the time to open Safari windows in new tabs. Is there a way to enable a middle-click equivalent with the Magic Mouse?

Comment: I drooled over this mouse the first time I saw it, but without middle click, I have no interest in it anymore.

Comment: **To new people answering: please read the FAQ (http://superuser.com/faq).** This is not a forum, this is a place to provide answers to questions. Avoid posting answers with only your personal opinion.

Comment: Guys, it took them 20 years to put a right button on their mice-- give them time.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here are two utilities that will allow you to customize gestures on the Magic Mouse, including adding middle click:

[MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/)

[Better Touch Tool](http://blog.boastr.net/)

Comment: MagicPrefs for the win.  I had trouble with Middleclick

Comment: +1 for MagicPrefs! Love the 4-finger click for bringing up Spaces (customizable of course)

Comment: finally -- i have my third mouse button. magicprefs is great!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the middle click just for opening links in a new tab in Safari, you can do so by pressing cmd while clicking.

Answer (score 9):

Try this software: [middleclick](http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/)

Works really well for me on my 2 year old G5 running 10.5.

Comment: Great suggestion!  I just tried MiddleClick with my Magic Mouse and it seems to work great!

Comment: Changed my mind after using Middleclick for awhile.  Middleclick kept registering spurious clicks for me.  MagicPrefs (see Jay's response) seems to work better.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Maybe later Apple or a third-part app will provide an update to add more feature.

Comment: Downvote because this is not true; see `⌘`+`Left Mouse` answers here.

Answer (score 3):

**MagicPrefs** seems not to work with the new **Apple Magic Mouse 2 (MLA02LL/A)**, when you try to customize the behavior of it, it shows a message indicating that the magic mouse was not detected.

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/) was the winner in my case, working on OS "El Capitan".

Answer (score 1):

I use [expogesture](http://ichiro.nnip.org/osx/Expogesture/index_en.html) on my Magic Mouse as I had missed expose, and the extra buttons mighty mouse had greatly.  You can designate "mouse gestures" and assign the Function keys (or any mapped keys really).  Works on Snow Leopard using the 10.4 download.  Just make sure your expose/dashboard/show desktop shortcut keys are mapped in system preferences.  I have the clockwise swipe assigned as "show all windows" and counter-clockwise swipe assigned as "show desktop".  Kinda like a "wax on, wax off" type of thing.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> quite often performs an action equivalent to <kbd>Middle Mouse</kbd> in many applications.

Comment: super-L click? Please explain.

Comment: The option+LeftMouse works in my TotalView.

Comment: I confirm that clicking on a link using `⌘`+`Left Mouse` works like `Middle Mouse` (opens link in a new tab) in Safari, Firefox and Chrome on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question when looking for <kbd>Middle Mouse</kbd> emulation when using iTerm2, where it is mapped to 'Paste from clipboard' by default. For others who use iTerm2, it is possible to emulate this behavior with a custom mapping in *Preferences > Pointer*.

Answer (score 1):

[Middle](https://middleclick.app) is a single-purpose app for adding the middle click to macOS for Magic Mouse and Apple trackpads. You can pick from a few gestures for each device, or hold the fn key and left click for a middle click. (I'm the developer, and the app is not free)

[image: Middle app preferences]

[Multitouch](https://multitouch.app) is an app for adding trackpad and Magic Mouse gestures to macOS, and middle clicking is one of the available actions that can be tied to a gesture. (I'm the developer, and the app is not free)

Comment: Middle doesn't seem to work for middle dragging. Is there any way to enable it? This is the standard for 3D modeling software. I'd happily pay the $4 if it supported that.

Comment: @adamdport which 3D modeling software are you using?

Comment: Fusion 360. Is it supposed to work?

Comment: @adamdport try v1.0.3, you can get it either via in app update or from https://middleclick.app.

Comment: Worked great and purchased! thank you!

Comment: https://middleclick.app/contact is giving me a 503. middle is causing right-click to get stuck, so left-clicking results in right-clicks everywhere. Can you help?

Comment: Sure, let me see if I can reproduce it. What's your gesture? The contact page uses recaptcha - perhaps your browser is preventing recaptcha from loading properly?

Comment: @adamdport try [v1.1.1](https://middleclick.app/downloads/Middle1.1.1.dmg) You can send me an email via my website for further troubleshooting: https://ryanhanson.dev

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/

and assign the new "middle click" to Expose or whatever function you'd like to have.

Answer (score 0):

I use BetterTouchTool (a 64bit app), and have middle click configured as a two finger tap, works extremely well and feels natural in Safari. The others I have are:
Show Desktop - three finger tap
Application switcher - single finger middle tap
Spaces - single finger middle click
Expose - three finger click

That's the main things I want, and they all work extremely well, hardly any false readings, no lag.

http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=195